# How to write a code for switch buttion in android that does not change its state when clicked?

Tags: android

When i click on switch buttion it doesnot change directly its state whether then it ask to the use to enable or disable the switch buttion.According to that the Switch buttion is change.

```
s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {`final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayBasicData.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("make decision");
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if(isChecked){
                                    s.setChecked(true);
                                }

                                dialog.cancel();
                            }

                        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.d("ygyu",""+isChecked);
                if(!isChecked ||isChecked){
                    s.setChecked(false);

                    dialog.dismiss();}

            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }`
```

Comment: why dont you play around with flag using true false....

Comment: But when i click the switch buttion it automatically change its state.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Simply do  not use switch button, use ImageView

Comment: Use this          switch.setEnabled(flase);

Comment: how can i do this using imageview

Comment: i reload the entire code please see it

Comment: if i use setEnabled then it does not fire event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its happening because you are not maintaing the last state of your switch button when ever you are showing alert dialog its comes to its default state.So just take a global variable and set your current state of your switch button to that global variable and check next time  your switch button state before you intialize alert dialog like that before your alert dialog.

```
        if (globalVariableLastState) {
            Log.d("state", "Maintain your switch button event");
        } else {
            Log.d("state", "Maintain your switch button event");
        }
```